# Met Office Weather Data - How to pass Lat/Long values instead?

Tags: python, json, api, weather-api

I am using the Met Office Weather API to pull in current weather data, the annoying thing is unlike most Weather API's this doesn't appear to let me provide a set of lat/long values and pinpoint the location using this. Instead it uses a 'LocationID' - but for the purpose of what I require this to do I need to be able to provide a set of latitude & longtitude values.

Currently the API works as follows :-

// just before the querystring is the value 354037 - this is the Met Office LocationID which links to a particular UK location.
http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/val/wxfcs/all/json/354037?res=3hourly&key=58c83b9e-17d4-4152-xxx-xxxxxxxxxx

Has anyone got this working to basically pass the MET Office API lat/long values instead?

Comment: Not really sure we can help you with this. That API either offers that feature or it doesn't. Perhaps there's some way of resolving a lat/lng to a location id...?!

Comment: It looks like the API can only be queried for 3000 locations - the locations had lat/long but I can not see a mechanism of using a lat/long - instead you need to look using a location code. Have a look at their docs http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/media/pdf/3/0/DataPoint_API_reference.pdf

Comment: I only ask as it seems crazy that almost every other Weather API does, but the Met Office are just awkward - Lat/Long is pretty much a standard on Weather API's... i'll post updates if I find a suitable solution.

Comment: Their API provides a way of getting a list of all regions via the val/wxfcs/all/datatype/sitelist endpoint. With this list you can find the nearest location to your requested lat/long pair, then use this location to look up the data you want.

Comment: I'd also be tempted to aggressively cache your requests, as you are limited to an average of one request every 18 seconds (burst limit of one request every 600ms) on the free tier.